# Method items cannot be found - Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a products and items table with a many to many relationship and a pivot table (item_product).

This is how my model looks like. When i try to retrieve items belonging to a product(category) `$selectedItems= $products->items()->get();` i get an error "Method  items cannot be found" .  I can't seem to find where my error is. Please help

**Product**

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item','item_product','product_id','item_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Item**

```
 public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','item_product','item_id','product_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
        $products = Product::all()->where('id',1);
        $myItems= $products->items()->get();
        return view('products',compact('myItems','products'));
```

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code. Is `$products` and instance of `Product` or a collection of `Product`?

Comment: `$products->items;` should work.... Laravel automagically converts the method to be accessed as a property of your products model, and executes the `get()` for you

Comment: @mtinsley look at my update.. the controller

Comment: @MarkBaker, i get the error `Property [items] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$products` not an instance of `Product`

Try this:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail(1);
$myItems = $product->items;
return view('products',compact('myItems','product'));
```

Explanation:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail(1);
```

This will fetch a single product model by ID, or throw an exception if that product does not exist.

```
$myItems = $product->items;
```

This will set `$myItems` to a collection of items. This is equivalent to:

```
$myItems = $product->items()->get();
```

I recommend you read the [documentation on relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: I am learning laravel but could you describe the difference between the collection and instance please?

Comment: i am getting another error `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: how does your answer resolve the `Trying to get property of non-object` issue

Comment: @XamarinDevil Using the code I posted you get that error? Which line?